# Generic class for UITableView

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, delegates

Is there a class or some way like ArrayAdapter in Android

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(this, R.layout.row,
    to, myList.);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

we just set the adapter to the listView(TableView in IOS). I am going to create this type of scenario.

For this I have created a class where all delegates of TableView are written.How would i connect `UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource` to that class.

**api_tableview.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol didSelectedProtocol<NSObject> // creating protocol

-(void)didSelectedProtocolMethod :(NSString *)str;

@end

@interface api_tableview : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tabledata;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UITableView *mytable;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UITableViewCell *cello;

-(void)initTableviewWithData:(UITableView *)table dataToShow:(NSMutableArray *)arr;

-(void)initTableviewAndTableCellWithData:(UITableView *)table cellObject:(UITableViewCell *)mycell dataToShow:(NSMutableArray *)arr;

@property(strong,nonatomic) id<didSelectedProtocol> didSelectedDelegate;//didSelectedProtocol

@end
```

**api_tableview.m**

```
#import "api_tableview.h"

@implementation api_tableview
{}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [_tabledata count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[self.tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text =[_tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // here we get the cell from the selected row.
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *texttoshow = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [self.didSelectedDelegate didSelectedProtocolMethod:texttoshow];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(void)initTableviewAndTableCellWithData:(UITableView *)table cellObject:(UITableViewCell *)mycell dataToShow:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    _mytable =table;

    _mytable.delegate =self;

    _mytable.dataSource =self;

    _tabledata =arr;

    _cello =mycell;
}
-(void)initTableviewWithData:(UITableView *)table dataToShow:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    _mytable =table;

    _mytable.delegate =self;

    _mytable.dataSource =self;

    _tabledata =arr;
}

@end
```

I have created a tableView property but if i get it here, I don't know how to connect it `UITableViewDatasource,UITableViewDelegate`

Suggest me a way.

Thanks in Advance...

**Edit**

I have succeed in creating what i want expect one thing. My class only works for default tableViewCell. How could i manage to send my tableViewCell and arrays or dictionary and it will set it according to my UITableCellView which i have designed.

**NOTE**

Now i have replaced the old code with new running one. now .h and .m are in running condition and working as i needed.

Comment: You will need a reference to the UITableView object to sets it's delegate and datasource to your 'api_tableview'-class.
Do you have such a reference?
Also worth noticing is that Obj-c classes start with a capital letter, just like in Java. :)

Comment: Read my Edit please. and suggest me a way to send UITableViewCell and its data in api_tableview

Answer (score 0):

you should set UITableView UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate. likes

```
_tableView.dataSource = self;
_tableView.delegate = self;
```

when you have the data,you only should call function of UITableView "reloadData", the the delegate  functions will work.

```
 [_tableView reloadData]  (MayBe you need this)


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_tabledata count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // 

      Class *data = [_tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // create Cell with data;
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: your answer help a lot . but now i want to pass UITableViewCell and set its outlets value accordingly . Suggest me a way